# Lost pictures after update to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I updated to Windows 10 recently.  I was in the process of transferring my pictures to a jump drive (I have a lot of pictures), but had not finished.  I had elected automatic updates.  When I got on the computer the next day, ALL of my pictures had disappeared, including from my daughter's wedding.  My picture folder is totally empty!  Is there some magic space they went?  How can I recover them?

Comment: The C:/Users/(yourusername)/Pictures/ folder went empty? Any other folder with missing data?

Comment: Have you checked under C:/Windows.Old/users/yourusername/pictures ?

Comment: Windows wouldn't have rebooted while a file transfer was happening **unless** it prompted you for confirmation and you confirmed the reboot should happen at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

In the Drive(Example `C:\`) where you Windows 10 was upgraded is there a folder called **Windows.old**

[image]

Inside you have the old Windows 7 Folder Structure and Files.

In other cases your files are stored in the Old Windows 7 User Profile and those files are in the `Users` folder in your system drive. After the update those files should remain there i mean Old Profile and New one.

If you still without find your files consider to use a File Recovery Tool, personally i suggest you [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) I could go deeper on their use but there is a lot of manuals un whole Internet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the missing documents/pictures have been found in the c:\Users\Public in the corresponding sub-folders

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem after updating window 10 a couple days ago: all pictures in "pictures" folder had gone!  After a day searching for the lost files, I almost gave up.  Finally, I found that all the pictures had moved to this location:

`C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Pictures\`

Good luck!